# Yii 2 widget "comunication"

Tags: yii2

I have a widget like this :

```
class ShowNewsWidget extends Widget{

    public function init(){
        parent::init();
    }


    public function run(){    
        $news = NewsModel::findAll(['not in ','id',$array]);

        /*
        HERE SHOW THE NEWS
        */
    }
}
```

I call this widget many times in the same page (one in layout, one in the view, one in the controller, etc...) , and I need to not show a single news 2 times on the same page . So I think to use a "not in" condition , but how can I make the widgets comunicate each other?  Using a singleton?

Thx
MS

Answer (score 2):

In Widget class:

```
class ShowNewsWidget extends Widget{

    public $exclude = []; // excluded news ids


    public function run(){

        $news = NewsModel::find()
            ->andFilterWhere(['not in ','id', $this->exclude])
            ->all();

    }
}
```

In View:

```
<?php echo ShowNewsWidget::widget([
    'exclude' => [1, 3]
]); ?>
```